# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML and script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, wysiwyg

I'm building a React application that use to deal with remote HTML content.

In fact, we're using a backoffice with WYSIWYG stuff, and so I need to retrieve that in my react app.

It works great for "standard" stuff, such as `<p>`, `<div>` etc...

Actually, I wanted to create content based on twitter, like embedding a timeline of tweets in a page of my application.

Here's the HTML I m getting from the backend API :

```
<div>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterAccount">Tweets by Twitter Account</a>
  <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Nothing more / less than the embedding stuff provided by twitter to make that work.

When I try to put it in :

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content}/>
```

It doesn't provide anything on the screen (except the link), but not the timeline, just like if (and I m sure it's because of that) the script tag isn't executed.

However, the stuff is present in my DOM and really looks like :

```
<div>
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/user">Tweets by User</a><br>
  <script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Does it exist a way to make that script executed?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the `src` attribute in the script tag, do a request with the url and once loaded `eval()` the text, but this is far from recommended.

Do you always expect the same script tag to appear in the html? perhaps including

```
<script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

in your page would work fine